# IOS: Notification only showing cross button not showing Category using GCM

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to show notification with UIMutableUserNotificationCategory in IOS but it only show default cross button not showing other buttons then i add in Category. It should be showing like this bellow. Is it possible or its not possible with GCM. This is how i add category in application didfinishlaunching

```
// Category
let releaseRoomCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
releaseRoomCategory.identifier = categoryID

    releaseRoomCategory.setActions([yesAction, noAction],
        forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)
    releaseRoomCategory.setActions([yesAction, noAction], forContext: .Default)

    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
    UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories:  NSSet(object: releaseRoomCategory) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

[image: this is how it suppose to show]

Comment: gcm should be used for android messaging, you should use apns apple push up notification service for iOS

Comment: server is using gcm for both IOS and android i m not sure ho can i get set category in gcm payload for IOS

Comment: You also need ApplePushNotification services, you need a certificate for that https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: yes i did that all and also get the notification but now i m not finding the way how can i pass category in gcm notificaion like { "aps": { "badge": 1, "alert": "Hello world!", “category”: “SHARE_CATEGORY” } }

Comment: According to the official doc of sending downstream messages from GCM here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream You can try to send category in `data` and deal with it later in your app.

Comment: "notification": ["body": "Hello from GCM dd","title" : "ooo"category": "RELEASEROOM_CATEGORY"], this is what i m sending gcm intrepret and shwo it i also try to add category but nothing happend not sure they provided its support yet

Answer (score 0):

Hi finally found the answer my self this is how its done for GCM

```
{"to": <reg_token>, "notification": {"body": "Hello from GCM", "click_action": "RELEASEROOM_CATEGORY"}}
```

click_action is represent category :D thanks every one :D